# Как присвоить новое значение элементу матрицы numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

У меня есть словарь слов текста(words_dic 254 слова) и есть множество предложений текста(k 22 предложения)
в матрице 22x253 я вывожу сколько раз слово из словаря встречается в данном предложении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        (c[i,j]+=1)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

У вас ошибка чисто питоновская, `numpy` тут вообще не при чём. Нельзя делать присваивание внутри скобок. Так всё работает (пробелов добавил просто для красоты):

```
        c[i,j] += 1
```